# The difference between nested and unnested requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations

```js
const foo = document.querySelector('#foo')
const nextFrameBtn = document.querySelector('#nextFrame')
const nextNestFrameBtn = document.querySelector('#nextNestFrame')

nextFrameBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  foo.classList.add('before')
  nextFrame(() => {
    foo.classList.remove('before')
    foo.classList.add('active')
    foo.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      foo.classList.remove('active')
    })
  })
})

nextNestFrameBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  foo.classList.add('before')
  nextNestFrame(() => {
    foo.classList.remove('before')
    foo.classList.add('active')
    foo.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      foo.classList.remove('active')
    })
  })
})


function nextFrame(f) {
  requestAnimationFrame(f)
}

function nextNestFrame(f) {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(f)
  })
}
```

```css
.before {
  color: red;
}

.active {
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<button id="nextFrame">nextFrame</button>
<button id="nextNestFrame">nextNestFrame</button>
<div id="foo">foo<div>
```

When is it necessary to call nextNestFrame to implement an animation?

I see in mdn that the requestAnimationFrame is executed before the redraw, I think there are some actions in there that affect the redraw, such as modifying the style of the node, will these styles be applied immediately or will they be applied on the next frame

Answer (score 1):

> When is it necessary to call `nextNestFrame` to implement an animation?

Never?

So what happens here is that browsers (Chrome and Firefox, Safari is different on all the line here) will perform the next "recalc" only right before the next paint action. `requestAnimationFrame` (*rAF*) callbacks will be executed even before that. So by the time the first *rAF* callback fires, the next "recalc" still won't have happened, and the CSSOM won't ever apply the styles associated with the class `before`.
When you wrap the *rAF* callback inside another *rAF* callback, you ensure that at least one repaint where the `before` class is applying has been made. This obviously also includes a "recalc".

But why would you ask the browser to actually paint that one frame with the `before` class applied? You don't need that one frame, what you need is for it to start the animation right away.
To do so, you can force a "recalc" manually. There are [many DOM properties / methods](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) that will do so, and generally speaking we want to avoid these, because when not handled correctly they can cost a lot of processing. A "recalc" will walk all the DOM to rebuild the CSSOM and all its boxes.
But this will happen anyway, just before the next paint. What matters is that we are aware of what we're doing, and how to get the better of it.

So the best is to batch all the operations that would need a *recalc* at the same time. This way we ensure that at most two *recalc* happened in that frame and no more. And the best place to batch all these operations is inside a [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) callback. Indeed, this callback is scheduled to fire a bit after *rAF* callbacks, right before the next paint operation, but right after the CSSOM *recalc*. So if we batch all our operations that do need an up to date CSSOM tree in that place, we ensure we're as close as possible to the paint action, we avoid multiple *recalc* operations and we ensure we don't paint one useless frame.

```js
// Schedule a callback right after the browser's recalc, but right before the next repaint
const callbacks = [];
let observer;
function afterRecalc(cb) {
  callbacks.push(cb);
  if (!observer) {
    observer = new ResizeObserver(() => {
      // avoid calling new callbacks right away
      const cbs = [...callbacks];
      callbacks.length = 0;
      for (const cb of cbs) {
        try { cb(); }
        catch (err) { reportError(err); }
      }
      observer.disconnect();
      observer = null;
    });
    observer.observe(document.body);
  }
}
// export default afterRecalc;

const foo = document.querySelector('#foo')
const button = document.querySelector('button')
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  foo.classList.add('before')
  afterRecalc(() => {
    foo.classList.add('active')
    foo.classList.remove('before');
    foo.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      foo.classList.remove('active')
    }, { once: true });
  });
});
```

```css
.before {
  color: red;
}

.active {
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<button>trigger</button>
<div id="foo">foo<div>
```

Though the best would be to start the animation using the [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate).

```js
const foo = document.querySelector('#foo')
const button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  foo.animate(
    [{ color: "red" }, { color: "" }],
    { duration: 2000 }
  );
});
```

```html
<button>trigger</button>
<div id="foo">foo<div>
```